# LuaLaTex "выделение" текста

Tags: latex

Не получается решить вопрос с выделением текста при использовании LuaLaTex, если собираю с pdfLaTeX - всё ок.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{extarticle}

\usepackage[X2,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
Проба пера.

This is test.

\hl{Проба пера.}

\hl{This is test.}

\end{document}
```

При исользовании LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{extarticle}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, HyphenChar="00AD]{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman} 
\setsansfont{Arial} 
\setmonofont{Courier New} 

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontrm}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Arial}


\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
Проба пера.

This is test.

\hl{Проба пера.}

\hl{This is test.}

\end{document}
```

Английский текст выделяет без проблем. `\hl{Проба пера.}` оставляет выделнным только `пера`, `Проба` не отображается вовсе.

В логе ни ошибок, ни warning-ов.

**Update:**

Итак, есть пакет [lua-ul](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/lua-ul) , который должен решить данную проблему. Я его собрал через `tex lua-ul.dt`, подключаю следующим образом:

```
% ifluatex

\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
......
\begin{document}

Проба пера.

This is test.

This package is \strikeThrough{useless} \underLine{awesome}!

\highLight{Проба пера}
\highLight{This is test}

\end{document}
```

Конструкции из пакета `\strikeThrough{useless}` и `\underLine{awesome}` работают отлично, а вот желанный `\highLight{This is test}` сыплет следующими ошибками:

```
! Use of \@highLight@@351744@{cmyk}{0,0,1,0} doesn't match its definition.
<argument> T
 his is test
l.59 \highLight{This is test}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

**Update 2**

Так, `The package requires LuaTeX version ≥ 1.12.0.`, у меня установлена `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)`. Стоить ли ломать систему и обновлять LuaTeX отдельно от  TeX Live?

Answer (score 0):

Итак, связался с разработчиком пакета. Он подтвердил, что пакет изначально разрабатывался для `LuaTeX версии ≥ 1.12.0.` и крайне рекомендовал перейти на данную версию. Пользователям TeXLive 2019 нужно подождать до апреля, в TeXLive 2020 LuaTeX будет уже нужной версии. Ну а для временного решения, автор прислал патченные стили для работы с LuaTeX 1.10.0.

Вот ссылка на [архив](https://yadi.sk/d/p9sYCecgXCLK9Q). Распакуйте в каталог с проектом. 
Подключаем `\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}`, 
используем - `\highLight{Проба пера, <<ёжики>>, \strikeThrough{зачёркнутый текст} \underLine{<<подчёркнутый>>}}`.

[image: ППример работы на рисунке]